# Adding styles to dynamically created component

Tags: css

I’m working on content driven Angular apps.

To give an overview,

- API will share the rich text JSON.
- Based on `type` field from response,  components will be created dynamically.

Below is the sample JSON,

```
            {
              text: 'This is paragraph', 
            }
```

Below code works for only one item, if I get multiple `text` items, it doesn't work.

```
  text(offset, length, text: string) {
        return text.substr(offset, length);
      }

      stlye(type: string, text: string): string {
        switch (type) {
          case 'blold': return `<b>${text}</b>`;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is with timing. I was unable to find out exactly where, but at the time the bold change was made, you eventually overwritten the original modified content. If you put a console log in the snippet that stylizes your component will understand what I'm saying

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.styleList.forEach(styleItem => {
    console.log(this.test.nativeElement.innerHTML)
    this.renderer.setProperty(this.test.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', this.test.nativeElement.innerHTML.replace(styleItem.styleText, styleItem.type));
  });

}, 1000);
```

I have not figured out exactly where the sync problem is, but I've managed to produce the expected result that might help you better understand the problem.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.styleList.forEach(styleItem => {
    const elements = this.test.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('bw-information-plain-text')
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
      this.renderer.setProperty(elements[i], 'innerHTML', 
      elements[i].innerHTML.replace(styleItem.styleText, styleItem.type));
    }
  });

}, 1000);
```

good luck

Comment: Thanks it works but, It's limited to `bw-information-plain-text`, What if I need to apply for this `bw-information-link` ? anyother options ?